# MySQL Query for ticketing system in custom back-end

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a ticketing system to a custom back-end that powers the rest of the site. I'm having a bit of trouble though in ordering the tickets (once a reply has been made). I am fairly new to MySQL and not quite sure how to proceed.

At the moment I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_tickets ORDER BY ti_date_last_reply DESC, ti_date_raised DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

The above works fine except that if a new ticket is raised the existing replies appear above it.

I have 4 ticket status stored in `ti_status` - **Open** (a new ticket), **Answered** (admin has replied to ticket), **Customer-Reply** (customer has replied or added more info to ticket), and **Closed** (ticket is closed).

What I would like is for the MySQL to order them by `ti_date_raised` if the ticket status is **Open** (oldest first), then add **Customer-Reply** which is found in `ti_date_last_reply` to slot into the correct time frame. Leaving **Answered** and **Closed** to appear below these queries (oldest to youngest) - but **Answered** goes above **Closed**

Example (I used date/time here, but I use Unix time in the scripts):

```
Date Raised      |   Date Replied   | Status  
----------------------------------------------------------  
2011-01-30-20-30 | -                | Open  
2011-01-31-01-00 | 2011-02-01-09-30 | Customer-Reply  
2011-02-01-10-30 | -                | Open  
2011-02-01-20-00 | 2011-02-01-20-30 | Answered  
2011-02-01-21-00 | 2011-02-01-20-35 | Closed
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Are the Status a foreign key to a lookup table? If so you can use that to order by originally and then by the dates required.

Comment: Status is within the same table containing the tickets. ie. ti_status, ti_date_raised, ti_date_last_reply are all in same table. Replies are held in a different table, but are referenced to the main ticket table above. Original message is held in same table as ti_status

Comment: At the least, is `ti_status` numeric?

Comment: No - I can consider changing to numeric. Will it result in faster queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_tickets
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ti_status,'Open,Customer-Reply,Answered,Closed'),
    IF(ti_status = 'Customer-Reply', ti_date_last_reply, ti_date_raised) DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Changing `ti_status` to a status ID number and storing the statuses (and sort number) in a second table will improve performance by a order of magnitude.